# SendGrid resource was not updated

Tags: email, azure, sendgrid, n-tier-architecture, quota

I have an Azure account with a SendGrid resource. Today SendGrid reached the quota of email sent per month, I am now trying to increase the tier of SendGrid.

However, when I try to do that I get this message:

> Your SendGrid resource was not updated to the selected pricing tier.

Does anyone know anything about this error?

Comment: I really doubt that anyone here will be able to help with this - it sounds like something that you can resolve via Azure Support (my understanding is that even if you don't have support in your subscription, you should still be able to raise a Billing Support ticket.  I would argue that this falls under that category.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I send the request to Azure Support, once I solve this problem, i'll put the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was create a new SendGrid account, for any reason the first one was cancelled so that I was not able to upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

Many times this has to do with the subscription and whether or not the subscription is allowed to use services in the Azure Marketplace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I send the request to Azure Support, once I solve this problem, i'll put the solution here.